# Two columns unique combine

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table like this

```
message_id | sender_id | recipient_id | message
6            677         681            message 0
7            677         678            message 1
9            677         678            message 2
10           677         681            message 3
11           677         698            message 4
12           678         677            message 5
```

i want to group sender_id and recipient_id unique between them with only one parameter. For example i want to select rows which relevant with user_id 677 table like this;

```
message_id | sender_id | recipient_id | message
10           677         681            message 3
11           677         698            message 4
12           678         677            message 5
```

I have been working on it for hours and I did not get the desired results.

Comment: Why did you include message 3 as it is duplicate of message 0?

Comment: because user (with id 677) send message to user (with id 681) at different times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
SELECT * 
  FROM message
 WHERE message_id 
    IN (SELECT MAX(message_id)
          FROM message
          GROUP BY CASE WHEN sender_id < recipient_id 
                        THEN CONCAT(CONCAT(sender_id, ','), recipient_id)
                        ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(recipient_id, ','), sender_id)
                    END)
ORDER BY message_id   ;
```

It just gets a combined key between sender_id and recipient_id to find the distinct records using group by.

SQL Fiddle Demo here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9df65c/11

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have added userid parameter, so list can be get for specific user_id http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9df65c/15

Comment: @hllktlhndd - No problem. Thanks for a challenging problem to solve:)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try... I'm not MySQL, but I think this will work for you.

```
Select Max(Message_ID), Sender_ID, Recipient_ID, Max(Message)
From Table
Where Sender_ID = 677 OR Recipient_ID = 677
Group By Sender_ID, Recipient_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.message_id = (select max(m2.message_id)
                      from messages m2
                      where (m2.sender_id, m2.receipient_id) in ( (m.sender_id, m.receipient_id), (m.receipient_id, m.sender_id) )
                     ) and
       677 in (m.sender_id, m.receipient_id);
```

Comment: @hllktlhndd . . . Duh!  I left the `max()` out.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #message
(message_id int null,
sender_id int null,
recipient_id int null,
message nchar(10) null )

insert into #message(message_id,sender_id,recipient_id,message)
values
(6,677,681,'message 0'),
(7,677,678,'message 1'),
(9,677,678,'message 2'),
(10,677,681,'message 3'),
(11,677,698,'message 4'),
(12,678,677,'message 5');

SELECT message_id,sender_id,recipient_id,message
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sender_id,recipient_id ORDER BY sender_id DESC) 'RowDistinctNumber'
      FROM #message
     )sub 
WHERE RowDistinctNumber = 1

message_id  sender_id   recipient_id message
----------- ----------- ------------ ----------
7           677         678          message 1 
10          677         681          message 3 
11          677         698          message 4 
12          678         677          message 5 

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I dont think MySQL has the function row_number()?